# How to fix user = [AuthDataResult?] nil and error - FIRAuthDomain code 17026

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a user registration component of my app and have `firebase` as my backend. When I try to create a user, it says the `user = [AuthDataResult]` nil and I get the `FIRAuthError` Domain.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated

```
if userName != "" && userEmail != "" && userPWField != "" {

            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: userEmail, password: userPWField){(user,error) in
                if user != nil {
                    print("User Has signed up")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotobiometrics", sender: sender)

                }

                if error != nil {
                    print(":(")
                }
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Enums/FIRAuthErrorCode#/c:@E@FIRAuthErrorCode@FIRAuthErrorCodeWeakPassword), the error code `17026`:

> Indicates an attempt to set a password that is considered too weak.

So you need to choose a strong password which should be long enough and better to include numbers, symbols, and capital letters.